# Is there or should have a basic knowledge summary here?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if it already exists.

I found that a lot of problems are basic knowledge, such as `HTML` form forget to write `method="POST"`

I am wondering if we can put together these basic knowledge?

I am not a master and nice to the new one, but if people often need to solve the confusion of meaningless basic questions, people will feel very bad.

**What do you think about it?**

*base on Google Translate*

Comment: Isn’t that what Stack Overflow is already doing? For very basic questions, askers should refer to some documentation. If you mean questions that are frequently asked, that’s what duplicates and close- or down-votes are for. If it’s an already answered question, flag as duplicate. If it’s a basic no-research question, downvote, possibly flag as off-topic. As for duplicates, there are some frequently asked questions that often get linked to “canonical” questions, as well.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, but how can I find out which one is duplicate the current question?

Comment: I usually Google with `site:stackoverflow.com`, then the relevant tag, then the underlying problem.

Comment: Users could hopefully find the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/info) and in the search to a canonical you can search for the [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhtml%5D+form+post+duplicate%3Ayes&mixed=0)

Comment: @qskane very basic questions tend to have very basic titles, it shouldn't be hard to find a duplicate even with the site search. I generally scan the question text to see if the problem described is the same and then I scan the top answers to see if they actually answer the question.

Comment: @Gimby i got your point, thank you  :)